# Create 1 list out of two list while intercalating (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

Im sure I did not explain myself in the title, for example, I would like to be able to create 1 list out of two different sheets while perfectly intercalating them in the order set.
For example the first list is: 1a, 2a, 3a, 4a, 5a & the second list is: 1b, 2b, 3b, 4b, 5b.
The result im looking for is a list intercalating them like the following: 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 4a, 4b, 5a, 5b.
Im not a coder myself but if it was possible to do this please let me know how to!

Answer (score 0):

It seems simple `FLATTEN()` formula should work for you. Try-

```
=FLATTEN(A1:B5)
```

In case of two different sheet, try-

```
=FLATTEN({Sheet1!A1:A5,Sheet2!A1:A5})
```

[image]